# Find and replace content within a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I literally cannot find the solution for this anywhere. Is it possible to find everything from `start` and `end`, and the content inside.

```
var start = "/* Start: User One */";
var end = "/* End: User One */";

var userCSS = "
/* Start: User One */ 
div.user_one {height: 700px;}
/* End: User One */

/* Start: Storm */ 
div.storm {height: 500px;}
/* End: Storm */";
```

I've added the start and end as I've already extracted them, but how do I do a search for the `start` and `end`, and then once I've the start and end found how do I replace everything from start to end. So ideally once I've found the following:

**This is what I am looking for, and ideally be able to replace it with a variable**

```
/* Start: User One */ 
div.user_one {height: 700px;}
/* End: User One */
```

I can replace it with a variable. I feel like since I'm searching for the start and end, this has to be some sort of regex solution, but my regex is heavily limited.

**New content variable**

```
/* Start: User One */ 
div.user_one {height: 500px;}
div.user_one h1 {height: 500px;}
/* End: User One */
```

**Input**

```
/* Start: User One */ 
div.user_one {height: 500px;}
/* End: User One */

/* Start: Storm */ 
div.storm {height: 500px;}
/* End: Storm */";
```

**Expected output**

```
/* Start: User One */ 
div.user_one {height: 500px;}
div.user_one h1 {height: 500px;}
/* End: User One */

/* Start: Storm */ 
div.storm {height: 500px;}
/* End: Storm */";
```

Comment: please add some examples and the code you tried.

Comment: what is the replacing variable ? Show the expected result after replacement

Comment: What is input? what is expected output?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Maybe replacing divs in a CSS is not the best solution. If you have many different options you could load different CSS files. For example: Start.css, Mid.css, End.css

Comment: @noumenal I want to replace the text via JavaScript.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz just updated my code.

Comment: Could you provide some more information why? How is your code relevant to the user?

Comment: @noumenal I don't have to explain why I want to do something.

Comment: I just want you to help me to help you. The reason you are receiving down votes is because you are not describing your problem with enough clarity. The reason you are having trouble finding a solution is due to using JS to replace parts of the CSS itself is not that common. There is a good reason for that and that is the separation between model and view. This design principle makes WYSIWYG that much easier to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for test case the needed replacement can be achieved by the following regex pattern and `String.replace` function:

```
var start = "/* Start: User One */",
    end = "/* End: User One */",
    userCSS = "/* Start: User One */ div.user_one {height: 700px;}/* End: User One *//* Start: Storm */ div.storm {height: 500px;}/* End: Storm */",
    newContent = "/* Start: User One */div.user_one {height: 500px;}div.user_one h1 {height: 500px;}/* End: User One */";

// you should always escape special characters in dynamic variables which are a part of a regular expression.    
var quote = function(str) {
        return str.replace(/([.?*+^$[\]/(){}|-])/g, "\\$1");
    },
    re = new RegExp(quote(start) + "[^/]+" + quote(end)),
    newCss = userCSS.replace(re, newContent);

console.log(newCss);
```

The output:

```
/* Start: User One */div.user_one {height: 500px;}div.user_one h1 {height: 500px;}/* End: User One *//* Start: Storm */ div.storm {height: 500px;}/* End: Storm */
```

Comment: That's perfect, but can I include the start/end in the regex so it's more dynamic?

Comment: yes, but note that you should always escape special characters in dynamic variables which are a part of a regular expression. See my update

Comment: I think that's the problem I was running into. Do you have any example how to escape start/end and then I can put them in the regex dynamically?

Comment: Hey @RomanPerekhrest I ran into a problem with this, what happens if I run into a single or double quote, it breaks the regex. Is it possible to add that regulation? I would really appreciate it as I've been stuck all morning!

Comment: I take it back, it seems to be the background: url(/bg.jpg);" (slash that is breaking it)